# Bazelisk build does not contain a toolchain for cpu error

Tags: bazel

I am trying to do a bazel build

```
bazelisk build -c opt --strip=ALWAYS     --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain     --fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/alta:mediapipe_object_detection.aar
```

And I got the following error

```
external/local_config_cc/BUILD:47:19: in cc_toolchain_suite rule @local_config_cc//:toolchain: cc_toolchain_suite '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'arm64-v8a'


ERROR: Analysis of target '//mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/alta:mediapipe_object_detection.aar' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' failed
```

I did use `fat_apk_cpu` option, and I made sure the android_sdk_repository is configured in `WORKSPACE`

Seeking some suggestions of what other things could go wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: any success on this?

Comment: Hi @max, sorry I can't remember the exact fix I did. Probably because I missed android ndk. You might try `setup_android_sdk_and_ndk.sh` as mentioned here: https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/android.html